# My question arises in spherical coordinate system

Tags: geometry

In the spherical coordinate system, we have 2 angles, namely the *azimuthal angle* and *polar angle*. My question is:

> Why does the azimuthal angle have the limit of $0<\phi<2\pi$ and why does the polar angle have the limit of $0<\theta<\pi$?

I would really love a graphical representation of the reason. I have taken $\phi$ as the azimuthal angle and $\theta$ as the polar angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to simplify I  will  use the followig, let  $\theta= \text{polar angle}$ and $\phi=\text{azimuthal angle}$. Then to expalin why usually  $\theta $ is taken in $[0;\pi]$, and  $\phi$ is taken in $[0,2\pi]$, we may consider the following:

In order to cover the whole sphere we may do the following:[image]

Consider this circle, if we rotate it horizantaly fom $0$ to $\pi$ we will cover a whole sphere, because when rotating  from $0$ to $\pi $ the  right half of the circle will cover  the right hemishere, at the same time the left half of the circle will cover the left hemishpere. Thus your sphere is cover by one circle (i.e. varying angle between  $0$ and $2\pi$), then rotating just by an angle  $\pi$.

Comment: The answer does make sense but what if I want to take a point in the left hemisphere

Comment: Yes, your point is again coverd by the bounds you take, as the left part of the circle covers the left hemisphere  when  rotating just  by $\pi$.

Comment: @AdnanArifSait you can whatch the first  0:08 of this video to see the way a circle is rotated to get a sphere. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oh-rOrCRTE8

Answer (score 0):

I guess the correct answer is "because somebody said so". Your question is about a definition that is nothing more than a matter of taste.

Comment: I am engineering student doing my bachelor's degree in electrical. I came across this in the subject ELECTROMAGNETIC THEORY. The book I am using is PRINCIPLES OF ELECTROMAGNETISM by MATTHEW N O SADIKU